# where can I find vim-enhanced resources?

Tags: linux, vim, editor, vi

I recently installed vim-enhanced , but I can't find any article/tutorial related to it.All I could find is a page that briefly describes it's new features , along with several RPM's to download . 
What exactly does it have to offer to scripting languages that regular vi/vim can't ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

According to [this](http://linux.maruhn.com/sec/vim-enhanced.html), vim-enhanced is just vim "with the perl, python, tcl, and cscope options compiled in." You should be able to find everything you need to know about these compile options in [the documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/help.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you're new to vim, then run vimtutor

You may also want to start out by reading :help and learning how to use the help system. In particular :help topic  (control-D)  and :help topic  (more useful if you have :set wildmenu) will help you find topics in vim's built-in help (which is notably superior to trying to Google for things). If all else fails there's also :helpgrep topic    and then use the quickfix buffer to see the hits (:cn, :cp, :cl, etc).

The #vim channel on Freenode IRC network is also a good place to get help.